# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: TinyTds::Error: Column, parameter, or variable #6: Cannot specify a column width on data type datetime

Tags: sql-server, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, tiny-tds

I'm getting this error while deploying on the production server.
I executed the same ruby migration files in the staging server and it's worked but in a production release getting errors like,

```
      01 /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm 3.2.0 do bundle exec rake db:migrate
      01 DEPRECATION WARNING: axlsx_rails has been renamed to caxlsx_rails. See http://github.com/caxlsx
      01 /var/www/new_zdm/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-7.0.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:111: warning: unde…
      01 == 20230621013249 CreateTenpoContractDetails: migrating =======================
      01 -- create_table(:tenpo_contract_details)
      01 rake aborted!
      01 StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
      01
      01 TinyTds::Error: Column, parameter, or variable #6: Cannot specify a column width on data type datetime.`
```

`
I didn't specify any width parameters in my migration.
I'm sharing a sample file of the migration file

```
class CreateTenpoContractDetails < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :tenpo_contract_details do |t|
      t.string    :payment_payee
      t.datetime  :tenpo_start_date
      t.datetime  :tenpo_end_date
      t.datetime  :next_yoyaku_date
      t.datetime  :tenpo_open_date
      t.datetime  :tenpo_agreement_date
      t.datetime  :contract_expiration_date
      t.datetime  :contract_start_period
      t.datetime  :contract_end_period
      t.integer   :total_contract_period
      t.integer   :revise_number_of_year
      t.datetime  :condition_revision_schedule_date
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Can anyone help me?

I searched many links regarding similar problems but didn't get a solution.

Ruby version: 3.2.0
Rails Version: 7